# UV wrap texture looks distorted in render mode

Tags: texturing, uv

Everything seems alright in edit mode, however; when I render the pill, it
looks distorted. What did I mess up?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Duplicated geometry causing z-fighting

Comment: Cam you provide me with the blend file you are using?